# Is (a + b)^2 = c+d solvable for {a,b} given {c,d} when {a,b,c,d} are all integers, and if so, what is that solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given (a + b)² = c+d where {a,b,c,d} are integers and  = (1+√5)/2 = the golden ratio, it's easy to calculate {c,d} from a known {a,b}. My question is how to do the reverse. Can {a,b} be determined from a known {c,d}? It's possible that there is no solution for a given {c,d). For example, when c=0 and d=1. However, any {c,d} generated from integers {a,b} will have a solution. So how can I determine if a given {c,d} is solvable, and if so, identify the solution?

I specified {a,b,c,d} to be integers. I could have specified them to be rational in which case whether the denominators of c and d are perfect squares or share common denominators might come into play in determining the solvability. Since any rational {a,b} can be scaled up by their two denominators to make {a,b,c,d} all integers, I have presumed that to already have been done so the problem is specified to be in the domain of integers. That said, if a solution requires the intermediate use of rationals, that is acceptable. In other words, for a valid soultion, {a,b,c,d} must all be integers, but the process of solving it may treat {a,b,c,d} as rationals having a denominator of 1. Ideally, the solution process should not extend beyond operations that are closed within the set of rationals and . For example, taking the square root of any of the {a,b,c,d} terms would require real numbers other than .

I am barely familiar with some very basic Galois field theory so I am aware that an answer as to whether a given {c,d} is solvable may come from that perspective. While I appreciate and welcome any such insight, I am ultimately more interested as a practical matter in how to answer the solvablility question and determine the solution algebraically when it is solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
(a+b\phi)^2 &=& a^2+2ab\phi+b^2\phi^2 \\
&=&a^2+2ab\phi+b^2(1+\phi) \\
&=& (a^2+b^2)+(2ab+b^2)\phi
\end{array}
$$.

So, your equation is equivalent to the system $a^2+b^2=c, 2ab+b^2=d$. The second equation gives you $a=\frac{d-b^2}{2b}$, which you can plug into the first equation : $\bigg(\frac{d-b^2}{2b}\bigg)^2+b^2=c$,
or $(d-b^2)^2+4b^4=4cb^2$ ; then you solve this for $b$ by putting $B=b^2$, solving $(d-B)^2+4B^2=4cB$ then solving $b^2=B$ for $b$.

Comment: The final step of solving b²=B could serve to tell me if an integer solution exists because I can determine if B is a perfect square or not using only operations that are closed under the rationals. Unfortunately, I don't see how to solve the prior step, namely (d−B)²+4B²=4cB, using only operations that are closed under the rationals. Specifically, I think it would require taking a square root which is not a closed operation in the rational field. 
If there is a method for taking a square root in a field like this that extends the rationals, then please let me know.

Comment: @David You seem to think the two steps are different, but in fact conceptually they are the same. If the quadratic form $(d-B)^2+4B^2-4cB$ has a rational (or integer) root, its discriminant is a rational (or integer) perfect square. Conversely, if the discriminant is a square, then you have a formula for the roots, and you can see if they are integers.

Comment: OK, I've heard the term discriminant, but I'll have to do a little research to unpack that answer and figure out exactly what that means as far as the computation process. Thanks for the pointer. I'll see where that gets me. Hopefully, you've nailed it. We'll see.

Comment: I had to refresh my memory and recall that the discriminant of a quadratic is "the part under the radical" in the quadratic equation. Since my original equation was stated in terms of a,b,c,d plus the additional B term that you incorporated, mapping all of those variables to the quadratic equation in which a,b,c and x have completely different meanings was a bit convoluted.

Comment: In the end, you helped me realize that I don't need to solve the whole quadratic formula to determine its solvability. Your explanation that knowing if the discriminant is a perfect square made it all fall into place and I was able to complete the algebra from there.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, and for my own future reference, I have posted another answer which builds on yours to flesh out the details and complete the process you described, but I'll still upvote yours as the prefered solution since I couldn't have solved it without your insight. Please let me know if you see any significant mistakes in my post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @David I didn't go into it in depth, but your post looks good to me. Thanks for your upvote

Comment: In case you're interested, I found one unexpected caveat when I implemented it. In practice I had to negate my calculated a & b in some cases. I just edited my post and added that as example 4.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer provided by @Ewan, I rewrote (d−B)²+4B²=4cB in terms of B. The result is 5B² -2(d+2c)B +d² = 0. From there, I identified the coresponding parts of the quadratic formula: x is B, the quadratic coefficient is 5, the linear coefficient is -2(d+2c) and the constant term is d². The discriminant therefore is (-2(d+2c))²-4(5d²) which reduces to 16(c²+cd-d²) which I'll call D.

The first step in determining solvability comes down to determining if D is a perfect square. If so, I'll call R=√D. If D<0, there's no integer solution. If D=0 or D=1, then R=D. Otherwise, if an integer value for R exists, it can be easily found with methods I needn't describe here. R can be pluged into the rest of the quadratic equation giving B=(-(-2(d+2c))±R)/2(5) which reduces to B=2(d+2c)±R)/10 giving two possible rational solutions for B. Since this step requires division, fractional results should be excluded from the solution.
Using the same technique, it can be determined if B is a perfect square. If so, then b=√B. If b=0 there is no solution. Otherwise, we can solve a=(d-b²)/2b. If the resulting value of 'a' is also an integer, then we have our solution  set {a,b}.

I discovered an unexpected caveat while implementing this algorithm. Since (a+b)² = (-a-b)², it's possible that even when c+d>0, we may derive a solution where a+b is negative. Since we want to consistently return the positive square root, we need to negate both a and b in the final step as in example #4.

Here are examples of some possible outcomes:

#1) When {c,d}={0,1}, we're asking for √ so there is no integer solution. Let's prove it.

D=16(c²+cd-d²)

D=16(0²+(0*1)-(1²))

D=-16

Since D<0, there is no real solution and thus no integer solution.

#2) When c is negative as in (-3,1), we're asking for a complex root so there is no integer solution. Let's prove it.

D=16(c²+cd-d²)

D=16((-3)²+(-3(1))-1²)

D=80

Since D is not a perfect square, there is no integer solution.

#3) Since (-5+3)² = 34-21, when {c,d}={34,-21}, the solution is {a,b}={-5,3}. Let's prove it.

D=16(c²+cd-d²)

D=16(34²+(34*-21)-(-21²))

D=16 which is a perfect square so R=4 and we continue.

B=(-(-2(d+2c))±R)/2(5)

B=(94±4)/10

B=(94+4)/10 or B=(94-4)/10

B=98/10 or B=9 The first result is not an integer so it is excluded.

B=9 is an integer and a perfect square so we continue.

b=√B=3

a=(d-b²)/2b

a=(-21-3²)/2(3)

a=-5

{a,b}={-5,3} as expected

#4) Since (-99+39)² = (99-39)² = 11322-6201, when {c,d}={11322,-6201}, the positive solution is {a,b}={99,-39}. Let's prove it.

D=16(c²+cd-d²)

D=16(11322²+(11322*-6201)-(-6201²))

D=312440976 which is a perfect square so R=17676 and we continue.

B=(-(-2(d+2c))±R)/2(5)

B=(32886±17676)/10

B=25281/5 or B=1521 The first result is not an integer so it is excluded.

B=1521 is an integer and a perfect square so we continue.

b=√B=39

a=(d-b²)/2b

a=(-6201-39²)/2(39)

a=-99

Since a+b<0, we need to negate both a and b:

a=99; b=-39

{a,b}={99,-39} as expected and the sign is now positive.